# pasar valores de campo jquery a php y guardarlos en base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

hola a todos tengo una situación donde tengo dos documento solicitar.php y guardarsolicitud.php

en el archivo solicitar.php tengo un para agregar campos.

```js
 var nextinput = 0;
        function AgregarCampos(){
        nextinput++;
        campo1 = '<div class="col-xs-2"><label for="sel1">N0. Empreado:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="# Empreado" id="Numero_Empreado' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="Numero_Empreado' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; /></div>';
        campo2 = '<div class="col-xs-2"> <label for="sel1">Fecha:</label><input type="date" class="form-control" id="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; /></div>';
        campo3 = '<div class="col-xs-2"> <label for="sel1">Area:</label><select class="form-control" id="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp;>\n\
                    <option>1.- Vacaciones</option>\n\
                    <option>2.- Tiempo X Tiempo</option>\n\
                    <option>3.- Permiso Falta</option>\n\
                    <option>3.- Horario Diferente de Trabajo</option>\n\
                    </select></div>';
        campo4 = '<div class="col-xs-2"><label for="sel1">Hora Inicio:</label><input type="time" class="form-control" id="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; /></div>';
        campo5 = '<div class="col-xs-2"><label for="sel1">Hora Fin:</label><input type="time" class="form-control" id="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; /></div>';
        campo6 = '<div class="col-xs-2"><label for="sel1">Solicitante:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; /></div>';
        campo7 = '<div class="col-xs-12"><label for="sel1">Causa Tiempo Extra:</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; ></textarea></div>';
        $("#campos").append(campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4,campo5,campo6,campo7);
        }
```

en el mismo documento tengo mi  con mi boton enviar

```js
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="php/Solicitud_Tiempo_extra.php" method="POST" novalidate>
          <div class="row">          
          <input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Añadir Elemento" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AgregarCampos();" />
                    <input type="button" id="btRemove" value="Eliminar Elemento" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <input type="button" id="btRemoveAll" value="Eliminar Todo" class="btn btn-primary" /><br />
          <div id="campos">
                  
                
                    </div>

           </div>
          </br>
           <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Solicitud</button>
           </div>
</form>
```

lo que quiero es enviar los valores de los campos que se van a estar llenando y agregando dinamicamente a mi archivo GuardarSolicitud y guardarlos en mi base de datos.

Comment: Supongo que lo que tienes en la funcion `AgregarCampos()` se va a pintar dentro de tu form, correcto? primera vez que ocupas un elemento `select` en tus formularios?

Comment: si así es, la función se va agregando dentro del form, y si soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: En lugar de un formulario, podrias usar Ajax

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo

Comment: @antoniosanchez como primera observación, para que puedas enviar datos desde un select al servidor debes crear bien estos, ya que tu actual elemento `<select>` en las `<option>` solo le estas pasando un nombre, deberias pasar el valor que enviaras a la db, algo asi -> `<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>`

Comment: ya coloque el <value> pero aun asi no me manda los valores para poder guardar el formulario

Answer (score 1):

Quizás tu planteamiento no sea muy ortodoxo pero creo que puede funcionar.

Te mando lo que tu planteas un poco más limpio y con las correcciones que necesitaba para funcionar. Hay otras formas de hacerlas con Ajax o con algún framework JavaScript pero creo que te vas a enterar mejor si te hablo de lo que conoces.

Lo primero es que cada campo que se envíe en el post necesita su propio nombre y esto no lo conseguías con tu código pues repetías la fórmula `name="campo' + nextinput + '"` para los distintos campos de una misma fila.

Por otro lado el botón de eliminar fila lo tienes que poner en cada una de ellas, no puede ser común (no te he puesto la función para borrar, eso te lo dejo a ti, pero ya tienes identificadores metidos para poder hacerlo bien.

Los campos "id" de cada "input" o "select" no te harían falta en este escenario pero te los he dejado ya que los habías puesto. Los "for" de los "label" tienen que coincidir con el "name", ya lo tienes también.

```js
var nextinput = 0;

function AgregarCampos() {
  nextinput++;
  var etiqueta_campo1 = 'numero_empreado[' + nextinput + ']';
  var etiqueta_campo2 = 'fecha[' + nextinput + ']';
  var etiqueta_campo3 =  'area[' + nextinput + ']';

  var inicio='<div id="fila_' + nextinput + '">';  
  var campo1 ='<div class="col-xs-2"><label for="' + etiqueta_campo1 + '">N0. Empreado:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="# Empreado" id="' + etiqueta_campo1 + '" name="' + etiqueta_campo1 + '"></div>';
   var campo2 ='<div class="col-xs-2"> <label for="' + etiqueta_campo2 + '">Fecha:</label><input type="date" class="form-control" id="' + etiqueta_campo2 + '" name="' + etiqueta_campo2 + '"></div>';
  var campo3 ='<div class="col-xs-2"> <label for="' + etiqueta_campo3 + '">Area:</label><select class="form-control" id="' + etiqueta_campo3 + '" name="' + etiqueta_campo3 + '"><option value="vacaciones">1.- Vacaciones</option><option value="tiempo">2.- Tiempo X Tiempo</option><option value="falta">3.- Permiso Falta</option><option value="horario">3.- Horario Diferente de Trabajo</option></select></div>';
  var fin = '</div><input type="button" id="btRemoveFila' + nextinput + '" value="Eliminar Elemento" class="btn btn-primary">';

  $("#campos").append(inicio+campo1+campo2+campo3+fin);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="php/Solicitud_Tiempo_extra.php" method="POST" novalidate>
  <label for="usuario">Solicitante</label><input type="text" name="usuario">    
  <input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Añadir Elemento" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AgregarCampos();">
  <input type="button" id="btRemoveAll" value="Eliminar Todo" class="btn btn-primary">
  
  <div id="campos">
  </div>
  
    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Solicitud</button></p>
</form>
```

Un fichero "Solicitud_Tiempo_extra.php" muy burdo para que veas que esto funciona sería:

```html
<?php

echo "<h1>Subformularios</h1>";

foreach ($_POST['numero_empreado'] as $key => $value){
    echo '<br>numero_empreado(' . $key . ")=" . $_POST['numero_empreado'][$key] ;
    echo 'fecha(' . $key . ")=" . $_POST['fecha'][$key];
    echo 'area(' . $key . ")=" . $_POST['fecha'][$key];
}
```